# select from two tables with certain sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this tables:

```
Relate : (ID,ArticleID,rArticleID)

TagInArticle: (ItemID,TagID,ArticleID)
```

I want to have the selection of two tables together. But the result of relate table show first
and result of `TagInArticle` table comes after that by its own sort by count

for select of per table I use this codes :

quey1:

```
select  ArticleID, COUNT(*) 
as counts from   TagInArticle  
where TagID in  ( select [TagID] 
from TagInArticle     
where ArticleID=5  ) and ArticleID!=5 
group by ArticleID
```

and :

query2:

```
select rArticleID from Relate
where ArticleID=1
```

if result of table TagInArticle was :

```
ArticleID    counts

1          |    1

5          |    3
```

and result of Relate table

```
ArticleID    

7
```

I want to show :

```
7

5

1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It is not clear what you are taring to achieve, could you please provide expected result.

Comment: i want to   result of relate table show first and then result of taginarticle table with above query show by a select that join this two results.

Comment: Since you want join these two queries in your question. I think the first query's two condition negate each other 1st you are select rows where ArticleID=5 and then you are select rows where ArticleID != 5. Does this query actually return any rows ???

Comment: Insted of order by r.ArticleID, write order by r.ArticleID desc at end of query

Comment: Also in your second query you are only selecting rArticleID = 1, how can you join this with ArticleID = 5 ??

Comment: i want to have this result. how can? with join or without it!

Comment: Simplezzzzzzz `SELECT .... (Query 1)  UNION ALL SELECT .... (Query 2)`

Comment: i know i can do this with union . but how can i have this sorting?

Comment: at the end of the all queries by just adding `ORDER BY 1 DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something you are looking for

```
SELECT R.ArticleID
      ,COUNT(T.ArticleID) AS Total
FROM Relate R INNER JOIN TagInArticle T
ON R.ArticleID = T.ArticleID
WHERE R.ArticleID = 1       
GROUP BY R.ArticleID
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

I dont have the foggiest clue what you are trying to do but after looking at your provided result sets you can do something like this.. A simple UNION ALL

```
SELECT ArticleID
(
select  ArticleID, COUNT(*) 
as counts from   TagInArticle  
where TagID in  ( select [TagID] 
from TagInArticle     
where ArticleID=5  ) and ArticleID!=5 
group by ArticleID 
)A
UNION ALL
select rArticleID 
from Relate
where ArticleID=1
```

Comment: i want to have a join that show quey2 and after that show quey1(with its sort)

Comment: when i have duplicates results. i cant use use union all and the sorting is not worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select  r.ArticleID, ta.TagIDCount as counts 
from   Relate as r
left join 
    (
        select ArticleID,count([TagID]) as TagIDCount
        from TagInArticle    
        group by  ArticleID
    )as   ta on ta.ArticleID = r.ArticleID
order by r.ArticleID desc
```

EDITED for Descending order

Comment: Error : Ambiguous column name 'ArticleID

Comment: You need to use Aliases in your select clause. Column `ArticleID` exists in your sub-query `ta` and as well as in `Relate` table.